# flutter type 'Rx<DateTime>' is not a subtype of type 'DateTime' in type cast

Tags: flutter, datetime, flutter-getx

I want to use a DateTime variable in getx
and use selectedDate in otherPage as variable in Condition
my Controller code  :

```
class HomeController extends GetxController {
  RxBool getMyPerm = false.obs;
  Rx<DateTime> selectedDate = DateTime.now().obs;
  @override
  void onInit() {
    // TODO: implement onInit
    super.onInit();
    selectedDate =
        DateTime(selectedDate.year, selectedDate.month, selectedDate.day);
  }
}
```

but flutter show me this error :
type Rx< DateTime> is not a subtype of type 'DateTime' in type cast

Comment: you have to add it to the sink.

Comment: @SimonDanninger how i can do it? do you have any Example for it?

Comment: use it: `selectedDate.value = DateTime(y,m,d);`

Comment: @RezaM mrc reza jan

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can't assign a DateTime to an Rx, this is the line that's causing the issue :

```
 selectedDate =  DateTime(selectedDate.year, selectedDate.month, selectedDate.day);
```

in order to assign the value of the RX variable you have to do it through the value property like the following :

```
 selectedDate.value =
    DateTime(selectedDate.year, selectedDate.month, selectedDate.day);
```